# VPC peering (2 VPCS are in 2 different account) via AWS CDK Typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I am trying to create cdk typescripts for vpc peering between 2 vpcs in 2 separate accounts. The relevant piece of code as follows. The vpcs are created fine, however I am not able to refer the vpcId and peerVpcId from the vpc1 and vpc2. Can anyone help please. Any working example code would be really helpful. Thanks.

---

```
//creation of vpc 1
export class vpc1 extends cdk.Stack {
constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: EnvProps) {
  super(scope, id, props);


const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'vpc1',{    
  cidr: props.vpcCidr ,
  enableDnsHostnames: true,
  enableDnsSupport: true,

  maxAzs: 3,
  subnetConfiguration: [{
      cidrMask: 24,               
      name: 'Public',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
  },
  {
    cidrMask: 24,
    name: 'Private',
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE,
  }],
  natGateways: 1
}); }}    


//creation of vpc 2
export class vpc2 extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: EnvProps) {
  super(scope, id, props);

const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'vpc2',{    
  cidr: props.vpcCidr ,
  enableDnsHostnames: true,
  enableDnsSupport: true,

  maxAzs: 3,
  subnetConfiguration: [{
      cidrMask: 24,               
      name: 'Public',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
  },
  {
    cidrMask: 24,
    name: 'Private',
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE,
  }],
  natGateways: 1
});

}}

export class vpcPeeringfisHiDev extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
       super(scope, id, props);
const vpc_peering = new ec2.CfnVPCPeeringConnection (this, 'vpcPeer',{
vpcId: vpc1.vpc.vpcId, //Error - Property 'vpc' does not exist on type 'typeof vpc1'.ts(2339)
peerVpcId: vpc2.vpc.vpcId  //Error - Property 'vpc' does not exist on type 'typeof vpc2'.ts(2339)
}); }}
```

Comment: Shoudn't it be `vpc1.vpcId` instead of `vpc1.vpc.vpcId`. Same for second reference?

Comment: tried that as well - got the error - Property 'vpcId' does not exist on type 'typeof vpc1'.ts(2339)

Answer (score -1):

You have to expose the `vpc: ec2.Vpc` constructs you're creating in their respective stacks so that `vpcPeeringfisHiDev` can use them:

```js
export class vpc1 extends cdk.Stack {
  readonly vpc: ec2.Vpc  // <-- add this

  constructor (...) {
    // :: instead of `const vpc =`
    this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc (...)
  }

  // ...
}

// :: do that for the vpc2 stack too

export interface VpcPeeringStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  vpc1: ec2.Vpc,
  vpc2: ec2.Vpc
}

export class VpcPeeringStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor (scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: VpcPeeringStackProps) {
    // ...
    const peering = new ec2.CfnVPCPeeringConnection(this, '...', {
      // :: now you can use them here
      vpcId: props.vpc1.vpcId,
      peerVpcId: props.vpc2.vpcId
    })
  }
}
```

then in your CDK app definition file, you'll need to pass in your references properly:

```js
const vpc1stack = new vpc1(app, 'vpc1')
const vpc2stack = new vpc2(app, 'vpc2')

// :: the peering stack --- note how we're passing in the 2 previous VPCs
new VpcPeeringStack(app, 'peering', {
  vpc1: vpc1stack.vpc,
  vpc2: vpc2stack.vpc
})
```

Comment: Arguably, you can make your whole setup easier too if you can consolidate your 2 VPCs and the corresponding peering connection into just one `cdk.Stack`, instead of having to pass along references like this too.

Comment: This is not helpful - the question was about VPCs in different accounts.